# Travelling from Interlaken to Lucerne

Tags: trains, tickets, switzerland, interrail

Is Interrail ticket valid for Glacier Express trains between Interlaken and Lucerne?  Do I need to make a reservation?

Comment: Glacier express goes from Zermatt to St. Moritz. The train between Interlaken and Lucerne is Golden pass and it has no compulsory reservation.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Interrail website](https://www.interrail.eu/en/plan-your-trip/trains-europe/scenic-trains/golden-pass) , Interrail passes are valid on the entire line (Montreux-Interlaken-Lucerne)

> Interrail passes are valid on the entire Golden Pass journey. Seat
>   reservation for groups is compulsory and for individuals recommended

Although they recommend making a reservation for individuals, in my experience it is not needed, especially on the Interlaken-lucerne section